# Spring MVC & Apache Tiles port to AngularJS/Backbone

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, backbone.js, apache-tiles

I'm stuck with a mess of a web application. The previous developer started porting the Spring MVC/Apache Tiles application to Backbone, there wasn't a RESTful API to support the port however and it's stuck in this funky state where JSPs are rendering the HTML and some JS which then loads a Backbone View. About half the API has been ported to REST but the application is still far being a true SPA and even further from being done properly.

I've got a strong background in Angular and little with Backbone but next to nothing with Spring & Apache Tiles. The application either needs to go back to server side templating or be rewritten to truly become a SPA with proper organization/testing.

If I start (properly) porting to Angular or Backbone, is it possible for the two frameworks to work together (Spring / Angular or Backbone)? I've done a port like this in the past from Django to Angular on Google App Engine and it wasn't too bad but the application has significantly smaller. Has anyone done something similar to this, if so I've been unable to find anything on how to go about doing so or if I should even try.

Comment: There's no reason the two techs can't exist side-by-side; any page can be either (a) completely server-driven, (b) mixed, or (c) completely client-side. "All" Spring is is a server-side technology that can deliver arbitrary data types: full HTML pages, JSON, partials, whatever.

Comment: Why not,you can use angular/backbone as your client and expose your back end as rest service using Spring MVC,it is pretty simple.

Comment: I didn't think there was a reason they couldn't, just very unsure of how I would go about integrating the two to run side-by-side while I do the port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you don't have a background in Spring & Tiles, it'll be difficult to learn & then port.

But if you're up for it :

```
1. Read about Spring (Dependency Injection & Configuration)
2. Read about Spring-MVC
3. Read about Tiles
```

Since, you already know about Django, you should be able to spot the similarities very soon. Once you become comfortable with Spring & Tiles, follow this approach :

```
1. Take a controller
2. Convert the JSP (which is returned by this controller) to a html template (used by Angular/Backbone)
3. Convert the model (data sent to the JSP) to JSON & start returning this JSON instead of the JSP
4. Create a route & test
5. Pick another controller
```

JSP is just a template & then model(data) is passed to create the actual html response, same as we do in case of Backbone (underscore template & then pass data to create the actual html).

This should be enough to start.

Comment: Following this method sounds like the approach I planned on taking. So what would an end result look like, does it essentially eliminate Tiles?

Comment: Yes, it should. Tiles is used to create layouts. With a front-end MVC talking to server in JSON, server-side layouting before returning response won't be required. Tiles will give you a good idea of how to structure your front-end views.